# Vaadin custom JS component refresh rate

Tags: javascript, gwt, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using custom js components in vaadin 8 (followin this documentation : https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html)

And I have found a problem for my component : if I spam (by programmation) the setValue method server side in a thread with a 100ms sleep, the client side skip a lot of events because notification rate between the server side and the client side seems to be linked to the global vaadin refresh rate.

If there a way to make the js rcp calls to be faster without breaking everything else ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after enabling push extension, added @Push annotation to my UI, and using lock and push on my ui in my spam thread, the refresh rate is high as we are now using websocket.

I can send notifications in a loop with 10ms sleep between each notification without any problem.